# SwiftUI line chart colored by series

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

How do I specify a custom color for each series on a SwiftUI line chart? The number and desired colors of the series are determined at runtime. The closest fit I've found is [chartForegroundStyleScale<DataValue, S>(_ mapping: KeyValuePairs<DataValue, S>)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/chartforegroundstylescale(_:)), but it takes a `KeyValuePairs`, which appears to only support compile-time initialization.

```swift
struct DataPoint: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let series: String
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    
    var id: DataPoint { self }
}

let data: [DataPoint] = [
    DataPoint(series: "A", x: 1, y: 1),
    DataPoint(series: "A", x: 2, y: 2),
    DataPoint(series: "B", x: 3, y: 1),
    DataPoint(series: "B", x: 4, y: 1),
]

// Hard-coded for this example. in practice, the series names and colors (and number of series) will vary at runtime.
let seriesColors: [String: Color] = [
    "A": Color.red,
    "B": Color.green
]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data) {
            LineMark(
                x: .value("X", $0.x),
                y: .value("Y", $0.y),
                series: .value("Series", $0.series))
        }
        .chartForegroundStyleScale(seriesColors) // Error: Cannot convert value of type '[String : Color]' to expected argument type 'KeyValuePairs<DataValue, S>'
    }
}
```

**Update:** Making `Color` conform to `Plottable` and using `foregroundStyle` didn't work. The chart treats all points as if they are from the first series it encounters. In this example, it plots a single brown line instead of a brown line and a purple line. Here's the conformance code:

```swift
let colorsBySeries: [String: Color] = ["A": .brown, "B": .purple]

extension Color: Plottable {
    public init?(primitivePlottable: String) { self = colorsBySeries[primitivePlottable]! }
    public var primitivePlottable: String { colorsBySeries.first { $0.value == self }!.key }
}
```

This is how I applied the style to `LineMark`:

```swift
.foregroundStyle(colorsBySeries[$0.series]!)
```

Comment: Color is a View, you can likely use UIColor and make it conform to plotabble

Comment: @loremipsum I tried, but ended up losing the distinction between the series. I updated the question with my attempt.

Comment: Can't you just use a "global" variable (say, a static - whatever) and cycle through colors?  Just use the Color constructor that lets you set the hue, brightness etc; fix the other two as you wish and cycle through hue by some step

Comment: @Fattie That approach resulted in the problem that I reported in my update, in which all the series were merged into one, with a single color. This is the code I tried: `.foregroundStyle(Color(red: $0.series == "A" ? 1 : 0, green: $0.series == "B" ? 1 : 0, blue: 0))`. The result was a single red line.